# Im watching vuetify width change but reload is not keeping the width

Tags: vue.js

hello. I have one question, my app is watching for the this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width property and updating a value that is used in a submenu.

Computed:

```
  computed: {
    width() {
      return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width
    },
  },

Watch: 
  watch: {
    width() {
      this.setSubMenuWidth()
    },
  },

setSubMenuWidth() {
    this.subMenuWidth = this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width
    this.$refs.submenu.style.width = this.subMenuWidth + 'px'
}
```

Resizing works but after reloading the changes are lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be all ok.
All you have to do is use mounted to run the method after the page is loaded or reloaded.

```
  mounted() {
    this.setSubMenuWidth()
  },
```

Edit:
I recommend you to check this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Vue has a life cycle, check it out.